# @code tag in Razor View is throwing compiler error

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor-server-side

While using @code, getting the error: The name Code doesn't exist in the current context

tried including namespace @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web but not helping. Same code is working fine in Razor component but want to know how to make it work in Razor view. Searched online but cannot find any solution.

`<input @bind="count" @bind:event="oninput" />`

`@code`
`{`
    `int count;`
`}`

above code should compile but throwing an error: The name Code doesn't exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the word code, just

```
@{
   int count; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For [@code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.0#code), it only applies to Razor components (.razor).

> This scenario only applies to Razor components (.razor).
>
> The @code block enables a Razor component to add C# members (fields,
>   properties, and methods) to a component

It is not supported in Razor View.